# How to get GO32 Unit file of freepascal

Tags: freepascal

I want Go32 unit file for migrating Turbo Pascal Application into 32 bit Win7 Application. Can anybody tell me, from where I can download Go32 Unit file of FreePascal?

Nitin

Answer (score 0):

The go32 unit is only available (and usable) with the 32-bit go32v2 DOS release, since it is the interface unit to functions that only that extender defines.

It is available precompiled in all Dos releases, and in every source package in the directory rtl/go32v2.